# How to read remote file from Windows to Linux with apache commons vfs?

Tags: java, filesystems, apache-commons

I have a file at Windows and I want to read this file from linux. Below code works fine when I try to run it from Windows but when I try to run from linux it gives;

```
"Could not read from "file:///10.0.0.1/C$/myfolder/test.txt" because it is not a file."
```

Here is my code;

```
    FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();
    DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(opts, auth);

    FileObject fo = VFS.getManager().resolveFile(remoteFilePath, opts);

    InputStream inputStream = fo.getContent().getInputStream(); //this line throws exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have the solution for you.

I had the same error and resolved it by setting the options like this:

```
private void readSFTP(){        
// ...
final FileObject sftpOriginObj = manager.resolveFile(ftpOrigin, getSFTPOptions());
// ...
}

    private static FileSystemOptions getSFTPOptions() throws FileSystemException {
            // Create SFTP options
            final FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();

            // SSH Key checking
            SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(opts, "no");

            // Using the following line will cause VFS to choose File System's Root
            // as VFS's root. If I wanted to use User's home as VFS's root then set
            // 2nd method parameter to "true"

            // Root directory set to user home
            SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);

            // Timeout is count by Milliseconds
            SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setTimeout(opts, 10000);

            return opts;
        }
```

Hope this helps.